# Помогите переписать код

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных

помогите переписать код на python. Задание было написать что то типа логики зоопарка.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Main {
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:\\E:\\DB";
    private static final String DB_Driver = "org.h2.Driver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        Connection connection;
        try {
            Class.forName(DB_Driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            System.out.println("connected to DB");

            String dropTable1 = "drop table CITY";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(dropTable1);
            stmt.execute();

            String dropTable2 = "drop table ZOO";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(dropTable2);
            stmt.execute();

            String dropTable3 = "drop table ANIMAL";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(dropTable3);
            stmt.execute();

            String dropTable4 = "drop table WORKER";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(dropTable4);
            stmt.execute();



            String createTable1 = "CREATE TABLE CITY(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255), zoo_names varchar(255))";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(createTable1);
            stmt.execute();

            String createTable2 = "CREATE TABLE ZOO(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255), animals varchar(255), FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES city(zoo_names))";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(createTable2);
            stmt.execute();

            String createTable3 = "CREATE TABLE ANIMAL(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255), worker_name varchar(255), FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES zoo(animals))";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(createTable3);
            stmt.execute();

            String createTable4 = "CREATE TABLE WORKER(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255), services varchar(255), FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES animal(worker_name))";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(createTable4);
            stmt.execute();




            String InsertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO CITY" + "(name, zoo_names) values" + "(?, ?)";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(InsertQuery1);
            stmt.setString(1, "Dallas");
            stmt.setString(2, "Dallas National Zoo");
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            String InsertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO ZOO" + "(name, animals) values" + "(?, ?)";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(InsertQuery2);
            stmt.setString(1, "Dallas National Zoo");
            stmt.setString(2, "Dinosaurs");
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            String InsertQuery3 = "INSERT INTO ANIMAL" + "(name, worker_name) values" + "(?, ?)";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(InsertQuery3);
            stmt.setString(1, "Dinosaurs");
            stmt.setString(2, "Jack");
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            String InsertQuery4 = "INSERT INTO WORKER" + "(name, services) values" + "(?, ?)";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(InsertQuery4);
            stmt.setString(1, "Jack");
            stmt.setString(2, "Cleaning");
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("\n");




            String SelectQuery1 = "select * from ANIMAL JOIN WORKER WHERE animal.worker_name = worker.name ";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(SelectQuery1);
            try(ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while(rs1.next()) {
                    int id = rs1.getInt("id");
                    String name = rs1.getString("worker_name");
                    System.out.println(id+", " + name);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\n");


            String SelectQuery2 = "select * from ZOO JOIN ANIMAL WHERE zoo.animals = animal.name";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(SelectQuery2);
            try(ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while(rs1.next()) {
                    int id = rs1.getInt("id");
                    String name = rs1.getString("animals");
                    System.out.println(id+", " + name);
                }
            }


            System.out.println("\n");

            String SelectQuery3 = "select * from CITY JOIN ZOO WHERE city.zoo_names = zoo.name";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(SelectQuery3);
            try(ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while(rs1.next()) {
                    int id = rs1.getInt("id");
                    String name = rs1.getString("zoo_names");
                    System.out.println(id+", " + name);
                }
            }

            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("there isn't JDBC driver for H2");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQL error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно и помочь, только скажите, в чем проблема. Иначе звучит как "перепишите за меня". Кстати, что такое "логика зоопарка"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли здесь кто-то за Вас полностью перепишет этот код, но вот несколько полезных, надеюсь, вещей:

- судя по [этому посту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495229/771848), Вы можете использовать [`psycopg2` драйвер](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) для Вашей H2 базы данных
- если я правильно помню, плэйсхолдеры в виде `?` поддерживаются этим драйвером, но Вы можете заменить на более стандартные `%s`
- `setString()` у Вас в пайтон коде не будет, так как вы будете передавать значения для плэйсхолдеров отдельным параметром, например:

  ```
  cursor.execute("""
      INSERT INTO 
          WORKER (name, services) 
      VALUES 
          (%s, %s)
  """, ("Jack", "Cleaning"))
  ```

  Обратите внимание, что мы тут использовали *multi-line string* - очень удобная вещь для читаемости SQL запросов внутри пайтон-кода.

Также, к сожалению, если я правильно понимаю, ни одна пайтоновская ORM-библиотека не поддерживает H2DB. Поэтому, похоже, вам придется иметь дело с миксом SQL и Python.